# how to update binding when the source's property changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

code like this:

```
<Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Converter={c:StatusTextConverter},RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

In the `StatusTextConverter`, I need two property of the source. 
I get the source object in the `StatusTextConverter` but it not update when a property of the source changed. why?

Comment: if I understand your problem well it's becaue it will trigger only when `Self` is changed, not when any of its properties has changed. You need `MultiBinding` and [`IMultiValueConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx). Then it will trigger when any of bound properties has changed

Comment: you get the idea. Is there any way to update  'Self' when a specified property changed?

Comment: MultiBinding will be better choice.

Comment: Also it's not good practice to use entire control in binding... In my opinion.

Comment: @Spawn thanks for your advises